# Is this Proposition on monotone functions true for ANY interval?

Tags: real-analysis

The proposition from Tao's analysis book is as follows:

Prop 10.3.3. Let $a < b$, and let $f:[a,b] \to R$ be a differentiable function. If $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then $f$ is strictly monotone increasing. If $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then $f$ is strictly monotone decreasing. If $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then $f$ is a constant function.

I wrote a proof for this and I'm thinking this proposition is true for ANY interval closed or open. So like if $f: R \to R$ or something it would be still hold true. Here was my proof for one case:

$~\\$

Suppose $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$. It follows that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ because we are given it is differential on $[a,b]$. Let $x_2 > x_1$ where $x_2,x_1 \in [a,b]$. We can say that $f|_{[x_1,x_2]}$ is continuous and differentiable on $[x_1, x_2]$ (or differentiable on $(x_1,x_2)$ if one does not want to talk about one-sided differentiability). By the mean value theorem, there exists an $x_0 \in (x_1, x_2)$ such that
$$ f'(x_0) = \frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}.$$
We know the derivative is always positive. It's also true that $x_2 - x_1$ is positive. Therefore $f(x_2) - f(x_1) > 0$. It follows that $f$ is strictly monotone increasing.

$~\\$

The mean value theorem needs a closed interval where the function is continuous but we create that by restricting the function. This proof should still hold fine for $f:R \to R$ where $f$ is differentiable on $R$. Do you agree? Is that true? If so then why was this proposition worded for closed intervals? It seems that would restrict its usefulness.

Comment: You may only know $f$ is differentiable over some $(a,b)$ for finite real $a<b$, then you cannot claim things at the endpoints...

Comment: @gt6989b If one only wants monotonicityof $f$ on $(a,b)$ then one need know nothing at all about the values (if any) and behavior of $f$ at the endpoints $a,b$ as monotonicity on $(a.b)$ says nothing about values of $f$ at those points.

Comment: @gt6989b The endpoints are limit points (i.e. [a,b]\{a} is an adherent point of the domain [a,b]) . I see nothing wrong with derivatives existing at endpoints. Perhaps this a more general thing found in Tao's book? Either way, Whether the domain is an open OR closed interval, it holds that the restriction is continuous on [x_1,x_2] and differentiable on (x_1,x_2). The restriction being differentiable on (x_1,x_2) is less than what I claim but it still allows for the use of the MVT.

Comment: Meant to say that $a$ is an adherent point of [a,b]\{a} which makes it a limit point.